# Exclude all subdirectories except one specific path in a find command

Tags: find

I use a `find` command to search for all files with a given extension within the current subdirectories ignoring certain directory path:

```
find -L . \( -wholename "*/ignoredPath" -o -wholename "*/ignoredPath2" \) -prune -o -name "*.ext"
```

This is working pretty well but now I want to ignore another path except one precise subdirectory in it. How to do this without listing all the subdirectories to ignore?

For instance if I have the following folder tree:

```
*/base/pathToIgnore1
*/base/subdir/requiredPath
*/base/subdir/pathToIgnore2
*/base/subdir/pathToIgnore3
*/base/pathToIgnore4
```

How can I write the `find` command ignore all `base` subdirectories except the path `*/base/subdir/requiredPath`?

I tried something like

```
find -L . \( -wholename "*/ignoredPath" -o -wholename "*/ignoredPath2" -o \( -wholename "*/base" -a ! -wholename "*/base/subdir/requiredPath" \) \) -prune -o -name "*.ext"
```

But it did not work, all the `base` subdirectories are ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find -L . \
  \( -type d \
    \( -path "*/ignore" -o -path "*/indeed" -o \
      \( -path "*/subdir/*" ! -path "*/subdir/save" \
      \) \
    \) \
  \) \
  -prune -o -print
```

If you want extra filter (like `-name "*.ext"`) you have to put that right before `-print`. The last part then looks like this

```
  -prune -o \( -name "*.ext" \) -print
```

Note that I changed the names for easier writeability and readability. Names starting with `i` are to be ignored. Names starting with `s` are to be shown. Names ending in `file` are files.

My tree looks like this:

```
$ find -printf "%y %p\n"
d .
d ./base
d ./base/subdir
d ./base/subdir/inform
f ./base/subdir/inform/imagefile
d ./base/subdir/isolate
f ./base/subdir/isolate/individualfile
f ./base/subdir/whatwhatinthefile
d ./base/subdir/save
f ./base/subdir/save/soundfile
f ./base/superfile
d ./base/indeed
f ./base/indeed/itemfile
d ./base/show
f ./base/show/startfile
d ./base/ignore
f ./base/ignore/importantfile
```

The output of the above command:

```
.
./base
./base/subdir
./base/subdir/whatwhatinthefile
./base/subdir/save
./base/subdir/save/soundfile
./base/superfile
./base/show
./base/show/startfile
```

Note that `whatwhatinthefile` in `base/subdir`. If you do not want the files in `base/subdir` then you have to exlude them explicitly. I tried but the command line became too ugly.

Depending on your use case it might be easier to define a shell function like this:

```
contrivedfind() {
  find -L . \
    \( -type d \
      \( -path "*/ignore" -o -path "*/indeed" -o -path "*/subdir" \
      \) \
    \) \
    -prune -o -print
  find -L ./base/subdir/save
}
```

Output is now:

```
.
./base
./base/superfile
./base/show
./base/show/startfile
./base/subdir/save
./base/subdir/save/soundfile
```

The only other thing different from before now is the missing `./base/subdir` entry. But I think that does not matter in your case because you want to filter for files anyway.

As before you have to put any extra filter before the `-print` in the first `find` and this time also at the end of the second `find`.

Comment: I did not tried your command yet but your example does not cover my use case. Based on the tree example you gave, what I am looking for is a rule to ignore everything within `base` except the specific `base/subdir/save` subtree.

Comment: @greydet see updated answer

Comment: You are right it is way more readable to make it in two commands! Thanks, I didn't think about this easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

You have to prevent that `*/base` itself is matched:

**Edit 1:**

```
find -L . -type d \
  \( -wholename "*/ignoredPath" -o -wholename "*/ignoredPath2" -o \
  \( -wholename "*/base/*" -a \
  \( ! -wholename "*/base/subdir" -a ! -wholename "*/base/subdir/*" \) \) -o \
  \( -wholename "*/base/subdir/*" -a \
  \( ! -wholename "*/base/subdir/requiredPath" -a ! -wholename "*/base/subdir/requiredPath/*" \) \) \) \
  -prune -o -print
```

This is a bit finicking: It prevents accidental matches of directories like `subdir2` which probably don't exist. But you never know... :-)

Comment: This also prints out directory names on my Debian, not just the `.ext` files.

Comment: @terdon Funny. You mean directory names != "*.ext" I assume.

Comment: @terdon Your edit: I need the "\", too. I made the mistake of copying the OP code in my answer. But of course the `find` command line can be broken into several lines by "\". That is shell stuff and has nothing to do with `find`.

Comment: You're quite right, the `\ ` was not working because the `(` were not escaped. You can check by running your original command. I changed it back since it is indeed correctly broken with the escaped parentheses. Sorry. As for the directory names, no I mean it prints directories, not only files with `.ext`, for example, ` ./ignoredPath2`.

Comment: This does not seem to work for me. I don't want to include the whole `subdir` but only `subdir/requiredPath` and its whole directory tree. When I adapt the proposed command with `-wholename "*/base/subdir/*" -a ! -wholename "*/base/subdir/requiredPath"` it does not find anything within `requiredPath` but find stuff within `base/pathToIgnore1` and `base/pathToIgnore4`

Comment: New version, see edit.